# Inverse kinematics solver

Tags: inverse-kinematics, ompl-planning, kdl, openrave, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,

I need to select an IK solver for a 5dof manipulator.

I took a look at the IK solver in ROS. There seems  at least two IK solvers. One is KDL which use extensively in arm_kinematics and pr2_arm_kinematics package. The other is Openrave (orrosplanning). Another one is OMPL motion planner,  which I'm not sure whether it has a built in IK solver or it just call the IK service from KDL.

Since we have a rather simple manipulator (5dof), it should have an analytical solution. I would like to get an analytical solution from the IK solver mentioned above. I know Openrave will give the analytic solution, but how about KDL? Does KDL only have the numerical solution? And how about OMPL, which kind of solution it use, analytic or numerical? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10407/inverse-kinematics-solver/) by [Fei Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/720/fei-liu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2011-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpenRave is the only package I know of that will generate analytic solutions for a generic arm.  arm_kinematics uses the kdl numeric solver, and ompl doesn't contain any kinematics solvers - it just uses whatever plugins you have configured for your system.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fei Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/720/fei-liu/) on 2011-06-27**:
Thank you for your answer. This clear my thoughts.

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-07**:
@egiljones is openrave compatible with older versions of ROS like ROS hydro?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are right, KDL will only give you the numerical solution, not the analytical solution.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fei Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/720/fei-liu/) on 2011-06-30**:
Thanks for your answer.

**Comment by [Fei Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/720/fei-liu/) on 2011-06-27**:
Thank you for your confirmation.